# I want to display department only if it contains hospital

Tags: python, django, django-templates

[Template displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nbpz.png)

```
{% for datas in form %}
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Name : {{datas.fullname}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Location : {{datas.location}}</p>
    <p class="card-text">Category : {{datas.category}}</p>

**Checking if datas.category contains hospital or not**

     {% if datas.category == 'HOSPITAL' or datas.category == 'Hospital' or datas.category == 'hospital' %} 

       {% for depart in dept %}
      <p class="card-text">Department Name : {{ depart.dept_name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
     {% else %} 
    {% for sers in ser %}
      <p class="card-text">Service Name : {{sers.service_name}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% endif %} 
    
    <a href="{% url 'provideredit' datas.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
    <a href="{% url 'providerview' datas.id %}" class="btn btn-info">View</a>
    <a href="{% url 'providerdelete' datas.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to display department if the category contains hospital else display services. Can anyone help me?

### VIEWS

```
class ProviderList(TemplateView):
template_name = "admin_section/provider_list.html"
form_class = ProfileCompletionForm
form_class1 = CustomUserCreationForm
model = ProfileCompletion
model1 = CustomUser
context = {}

def get(self,request,*awrgs,**kwargs):
    # obj1 = self.model1.objects.all()
    list1 =[]
    list3 = []
    list4 = []
    # for datas in obj1:
        # print(datas)
    qs = self.model.objects.all()
    for datas in qs:
        # print(datas.user_id)
        # query = datas.category,datas.id,datas.services
        dept = datas.departments.filter(id=datas.id)
        list3 += dept
        print(list3)
        ser = datas.services.filter(services=datas.id)
        # print(dept)
        list4 += ser
        # for obj in qs:
        #     query = obj.id,obj.fullname,obj.location,obj.category,obj.departments
    # list1 += qs
    print(list3,";",list4)
    self.context['form'] = qs
    self.context['dept'] = list3
    self.context['ser'] = list4
    form = SearchForm
    self.context['search'] = form
    return render(request,self.template_name,self.context)
```

here in the view I have used list[] function in order to append the datas and used list += data as per an answer from stackoverflow itsel.

### Models

```
class ProfileCompletion(models.Model):
fullname = models.CharField(max_length=120,default=None)
address = models.CharField(max_length=800,default=None)
location = models.PointField(default=Point(0, 0),geography=True)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department, related_name='departments',blank=True)
services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, related_name='services',blank=True)


user=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Updated the question with models and views.

Comment: You should do this in the view or the models. Can you share the model of `datas` and the view where you render this template?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please see the updated question.